# None of your e-mail accounts could send to this recipient

Tags: email, exchange, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

We are running Exchange 2010 SP2 (v 14.2, build 247.5) in our organization.  We have one exchange server and a separate AD/DNS server.  We installed it from scratch (not an upgrade or migration from anything previous) late last year.

We have some users who are getting bounced emails like the following:

> From: System Administrator
>   Sent: Monday, March 19, 2012 2:35 PM
>   Subject: Undeliverable: Website Change
>
> Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.
>
> Subject: Website Change
>   Sent: 3/19/2012 2:35 PM
>
> The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:
>
> 'xxx@wxxxxxx.com' on 3/19/2012 2:35 PM
>   None of your e-mail accounts could send to this recipient.

I did some digging and saw mention if corrupt autocomplete cache.  So I had the affected users delete the record in the cache and type it by hand.  Same thing, only with a twist.  Got the bounce below:

> -----Original Message-----
>   From: Microsoft Outlook
>   Sent: Wednesday, March 21, 2012 9:31 AM
>   To: AC Smith
>   Subject: Undeliverable: Missing Mill Cert
>
> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> 'jane.d@company-address.com.br' (MAILTO:jane.d@company-address.com.br) 
>   A problem occurred and this message couldn't be delivered. Check to be sure the e-mail address is correct. If the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.
>
> Diagnostic information for administrators:
>
> Generating server: EXCHANGE.mycompany.local
>
> IMCEAMAILTO-jane%2B2Ed%2B40company-address%2B2Ecom%2B2Ebr@mycompany.com
>
> #550 5.4.4 ROUTING.NoConnectorForAddressType; unable to route for address type ##
>
> Original message headers:
>
> Received: from EXCHANGE.mycompany.local ([asdf:sdfg:5337:dfgh:246c]) by
>   Exchange.mycompany.local ([asdf::sdfg:dfgh:f7e8:246c%18]) with mapi id
>   14.02.0247.003; Wed, 21 Mar 2012 09:30:35 -0500
>   Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>   From: AC Smith 
>   To: "'jane.d@company-address.com.br'"
>   
>   Subject: Missing Mill Cert
>   Thread-Topic: Missing Mill Cert
>   Thread-Index: Ac0Hbzl5e+fCXE21Qda8NwUkeRRj3g==
>   Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 09:30:34 -0500
>   Message-ID: <79F049F90788B84B96E26063E2E2268A0D617251@Exchange.mycompany.local>
>   Accept-Language: en-US
>   Content-Language: en-US
>   X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
>   X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <79F049F90788B84B96E26063E2E2268A0D617251@Exchange.mycompany.local>
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   X-Originating-IP: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

**Now, from the information above, I'm pretty sure that this is the problem:**

```
'jane.d@company-address.com.br' (MAILTO:jane.d@company-address.com.br) <mailto:IMCEAMAILTO-jane%2B2Ed%2B40company-address%2B2Ecom%2B2Ebr@mycompany.com>
```

*Why on earth is it trying to send to customeraddress@MYADDRESS.com ????*

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently this is an issue with `mailto:` links in Office 2007.

Either apply [KB2475888](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2475888/en-us) or remove KB2344993, according to posts in this technet thread: [IMCEAMAILTO issue causing "Delivery has failed ...".](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvradmin/thread/56b2d50d-6855-444b-abed-89aaa9176a9f)

To work around this issue, just have the users remove the cached contact entries from Outlook by typing the name in the "To:" field, and then click the little black cross next to the recipients/contacts that resolve to these strange IMCEAMAILTO addresses.

Input the correct email address manually, and it'll be there next time you try to send from Outlook

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.  Odd, because we're using office2010.

Comment: [KB2597052](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597052) contains a hotfix for word 2010